# How to integrate smartystreet with laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8, smartystreets

I want to integrated smartystreets with my laravel project but am not able to do so.

I have tried this [link](https://packagist.org/packages/fireenginered/smartystreets-laravel) , but it throw me error "Undefined constant 'FireEngineRed\SmartyStreetsLaravel\SmartyStreetsServiceProvider'" when i run "$ php artisan vendor:publish".
Any help would be appreciated.`

Comment: I'm not sure how that package works, but I would recommend trying the offical PHP sdk if you haven't already https://packagist.org/packages/smartystreets/phpsdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in step 2 of the above [link](https://packagist.org/packages/fireenginered/smartystreets-laravel) worked for me:

change this:

```
'providers' => array( 
   ... 
  'FireEngineRed\SmartyStreetsLaravel\SmartyStreetsServiceProvider', 
) 
'aliases' => array(
 ... 
'SmartyStreets' => 'FireEngineRed\SmartyStreetsLaravel\SmartyStreetsFacade',
 )
```

to this:

```
'providers' => [ 
   ...
   FireEngineRed\SmartyStreetsLaravel\SmartyStreetsServiceProvider::class,
 ],
'aliases' => [ 
 ...
 'SmartyStreets'  = > FireEngineRed\SmartyStreetsLaravel\SmartyStreetsFacade::class,
 ],
```

Note:Add the SmartyStreets providers and aliases element at the end of the both array.